# How can I prevent my li's from going below my menu even if there is no room?

Tags: css, css-float

I have created a menu but cannot solve this issue so I am hoping that someone can help me:(

**Problem** my last li (anchor tag) inside my menu keeps collapsing underneath my menu and no matter I do problem persists. In Firefox looks fine but in every other browser it is a disaster... 
I have tried: adding overflow:hidden; to my menuwrapper,tried adding a "clear both" div after last ul tag,added display:inline-block to li tags,and a lot of other approaches to my problem but nothing works:( 
I didn't set explicit width to my anchor tags (**I *really* don't want to do that!**). 
In Firefox looks like perfect: 
http://robertpeic.com/kyani/template/menu.png 

in other browsers look like this: (*notice that there is no blue button because it came bellow my menu*) 
http://robertpeic.com/kyani/template/menu2.png
 
I dont want this:
http://robertpeic.com/kyani/template/menu3.png

**Question:** How can I prevent my li's from going below my menu even if there is no room? 
Thanks for your help!!

[**Link to my menu**](http://robertpeic.com/kyani/)

Relevant CSS looks like this:

```
.mainmenu{
display:block;
width:906px;
margin:0px auto;
height:42px;
background-image:url('http://robertpeic.com/kyani/template/mainmenubg.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
position:relative;
margin-top:-15px;
z-index:160;
}

.mainmenu ul{
list-style-type:none;
}

.mainmenu ul li {
float:left;
}

.mainmenu ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
font-family:"Palatino Linotype","Book Antiqua",Palatino,FreeSerif,serif;
font-size:20px;
padding:0 23px 0 23px;
color:#383838;
border-left:1px solid #dedede;
height:42px;
line-height:42px;
z-index:100;
}

.mainmenu ul li a:hover{
color:#ffffff;
}

.mainHover{
background-image:url('http://robertpeic.com/kyani/template/hoverm.png');
display:block;
position:relative;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
z-index:-50;
}
```

Html looks like:

```
<div class="mainmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Početna</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ky&auml;ni</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Trokut zdravlja</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Poslovna prilika</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Info predavanja</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--/mainmenu-->
```

Comment: "How can I prevent my li's from going below my menu even if there is no room?" = how can I fill a container with more than it can hold. I guess, make the container wider. That is set `.mainmenu` to more than 906px

Comment: If i do that then on hover there will be "white space" on right side of my last li tag(not an option)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so dumb right now :) To prevent my li from going below I've only wrapped my menu with other div and set that div to overflow hidden and it worked perfect! THX everybody for your help!!!

CSS now looks like:

```
.mainmenu{
 display:block;
 width:903px;
 }

 .mainmenu ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 }

 .mainmenu ul li {
 float:left;
  }

 .mainmenu ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 font-family:"Palatino Linotype","Book Antiqua",Palatino,FreeSerif,serif;
 font-size:20px;
 padding:0 23px 0 23px;
 color:#383838;
 border-left:1px solid #dedede;
 height:42px;
 line-height:42px;
 z-index:100;
 }

 .mainmenu ul li a:hover{
 color:#ffffff;
 }

.menuwrap{
margin:0px auto;
height:42px;
background-image:url('http://robertpeic.com/kyani/template/mainmenubg.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
position:relative;
margin-top:-15px;
z-index:160;
width:900px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML looks like this:

```
      <div class="menwrap">
      <div class="mainmenu">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Početna</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ky&auml;ni</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trokut zdravlja</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Poslovna prilika</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Info predavanja</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div><!--/mainmenu-->
      </div><!--/menuwrap-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `overflow:hidden` to `.mainmenu` and changed the padding for `.mainmenu ul li a` and it worked for me.

```
.mainmenu
overflow:hidden;

.mainmenu ul li a
padding:0 22px 0 23px;
```

I have found that the best way to get a consistent full width menu bar with cross browser compatibility is to force the widths of the LIs. Although it isn't a very forward compatible. it is the best way I have found for maintaining the integrity of the visual design.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the mainmenu div to 910px. It will solve your problem and also not show any white spacing

Answer (score 0):

Your entire html will be, as given below. While testing your code,I found, if I omit the first line DocType... the menu gets mangled in IE . In Chrome it works fine. So AFAIK, Your issue was with Doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <style>
            .mainmenu
            {
                display: block;
                width: 906px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                height: 42px;
                background-image: url('http://robertpeic.com/kyani/template/mainmenubg.jpg');
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                position: relative;
                margin-top: -15px;
                z-index: 160;
            }

            .mainmenu ul
            {
                list-style-type: none;
            }

            .mainmenu ul li
            {
                float: left;
            }

            .mainmenu ul li a
            {
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                font-family: "Palatino Linotype" , "Book Antiqua" ,Palatino,FreeSerif,serif;
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 0 20px ;
                color: #383838;
                border-left: 1px solid #dedede;
                height: 42px;
                line-height: 42px;
                z-index: 100;
            }

            .mainmenu ul li a:hover
            {
                color: #ffffff;
            }

            .mainHover
            {
                background-image: url('http://robertpeic.com/kyani/template/hoverm.png');
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                z-index: -50;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Pocetna</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ky&auml;ni</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trokut zdravlja</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Poslovna prilika</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Info predavanja</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ThX for your help:) But it is not what I want i have added a another screenshot of what is bugging me if anybody can help that would bee cool...

Comment: @DejoDekic : This is bcoz of padding and the width of the UL, div. Open the page in IE8 or + . Hit F12 and play with css on runtime. You will get you shot.